# Verify Mock calls in a particular test

Tags: java, mockito, testng

In one of my Unit tests, I am trying to verify if one of my mock methods was never called. And the issue is that this mock is a global `@beforeClass` mock common for a lot of other tests.

So, when I try to verify if the mock is never called or not, it always fails, as other tests are calling that mock. Is there a way using Mockito to verify the mock invocation only for that test ?

One solution I can think of is converting my common mock from `@BeforeClass` to `@Before` (so that before each test, the mock is is re-created). But wanted to check if there are any other solutions without touching the common `BeforeClass` mocks.

```java
@BeforeClass
  public void before() {
    someClassMock = mock(someClass.class);
    when(someClassMock.aMethodCall(any()).thenReturn(true);
  }

// Bunch of tests


  @Test
  public void oneOfTheManytest(){
  //some code where someClassMock.aMethodCall is NOT called

    verify(someClassMock, never()).aMethodCall(any());
    // ^^ This always fails, even when I am sure this mock 
    // is not called for this test. 
    // I think this looks if this mock is called or not overall for this test file.

  }
```

Can someone help with a solution where I can verify mock method invocation for a specific test ?

Comment: You already found a solution: *One solution I can think of is converting my common mock from \@BeforeClass to @Before (so that before each test, the mock is is re-created)*

Comment: That was one solution that I was thinking, but wanted to check if there are any other simpler solutions, as the @BeforeClass common mocks have a lot of mocks.

Comment: You don't have to move all mocks to `@Before`, only the needed ones.

Comment: Actually there are a lot of mocks with different combination of the input params, that I am wary to touch; also multiple mock methods; I just simplified the problem definition for simplicity.

Comment: an alternative is to [`reset`](https://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/2.27.0/org/mockito/Mockito.html#17) your mock in your test.

Answer (score 0):

I can infer here that your tests don't follow AAA. Each test should be runnable individually and it's success shouldn't depend on the execution of other tests.

Your best bet would be to extract the mock setup you need to repeat into a helper method, and call it within the arrange section of your test.